# Adding labels on ggplot facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add significance tests' letters from a two way ANOVA in a two faceted graph. The problem is, if a try using geom_text, the function works well until it reaches the level 5 of my plots, i.e., the end of the first facet. After this, it repeats the same 5 values for the second facet, but I need to have new values there.

I have tried `annotation` and `ggpub`, but both don't seem to solve the problem.

Here is an example:

The data frame:

```
ex=structure(list(Trat = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "Ca", "Ca", "Ca", 
"Ca", "N", "N", "N", "N", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "P", "P", "P", 
"P", "C", "C", "C", "C", "Ca", "Ca", "Ca", "Ca", "N", "N", "N", 
"N", "NP", "NP", "NP", "NP", "P", "P", "P", "P"), Ano = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2009", "2015"), class = 
"factor"), 
Trat.Ano = c("C . 2009", "C . 2009", "C . 2009", "C . 2009", 
"Ca . 2009", "Ca . 2009", "Ca . 2009", "Ca . 2009", "N . 2009", 
"N . 2009", "N . 2009", "N . 2009", "NP . 2009", "NP . 2009", 
"NP . 2009", "NP . 2009", "P . 2009", "P . 2009", "P . 2009", 
"P . 2009", "C . 2015", "C . 2015", "C . 2015", "C . 2015", 
"Ca . 2015", "Ca . 2015", "Ca . 2015", "Ca . 2015", "N . 2015", 
"N . 2015", "N . 2015", "N . 2015", "NP . 2015", "NP . 2015", 
"NP . 2015", "NP . 2015", "P . 2015", "P . 2015", "P . 2015", 
"P . 2015"), Especie = c("Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", 
"Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", 
"Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", 
"Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp", 
"Sp", "Sp", "Sp", "Sp"), cobertura = c(0, 0, 0, 7, 11, 0, 
8, 314, 0, 0, 0, 0, 451, 1398, 1400, 712, 1305, 1063, 1068, 
161, 0, 0, 0, 0, 810, 325, 511, 678, 0, 0, 0, 0, 326, 1043, 
57, 229, 701, 1488, 62, 987)), row.names = c(1L, 4L, 7L, 
10L, 13L, 16L, 19L, 22L, 25L, 28L, 31L, 34L, 37L, 40L, 43L, 46L, 
49L, 52L, 55L, 58L, 61L, 64L, 67L, 70L, 73L, 76L, 79L, 82L, 85L, 
88L, 91L, 94L, 97L, 100L, 103L, 106L, 109L, 112L, 115L, 118L), class = 
"data.frame")
```

ANOVA:

```
fitMelinis1<- aov(cobertura~Trat*Ano, data=ex) ## Two Way anova
TukeyMelinis1=TukeyHSD(fitMelinis1) # PairWise test
teste=multcompView::multcompLetters4(fitMelinis1, TukeyMelinis1) # the letters I want in my graph
```

See that the letters are repeated in both facets.

```
Paleta=c("#339900", "#FF0000", "#000099", "#DAA523", "#000000")

plotMelinis=ggplot(ex,aes(x=Trat,y=cobertura,fill=Trat))+
geom_boxplot() + scale_fill_manual(values=Paleta)+
ylab("cobertura")+ggtitle("Melinis")+facet_wrap(~Ano,ncol=2)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 1, y = 1500, label = "c", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 2, y = 1500, label = "bc", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 3, y = 1500, label = "c", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 4, y = 1500, label = "a", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 5, y = 1500, label = "a", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 6, y = 1500, label = "c", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 7, y = 1500, label = "abc", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 8, y = 1500, label = "c", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 9, y = 1500, label = "abc", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)+
geom_text(data = ex, x = 10, y = 1500, label = "ab", color = "black", 
family="serif", size = 4)
```

So, as said, I'd like to have different letters on each facet.

[image: Repeated letters in each facet]

Comment: This is an example of why you want to work with data in a long format for `ggplot`. Instead of hard-coding your x, y, and label for each piece of text, just make a data frame of that information and treat it as you would any other data in `ggplot`

Comment: It's also hard to tell what's what. Does the ANOVA-related stuff occur in the plotting? If not, we don't need it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `stat_summary`:

```
#labels need to be ordered based on the year and Trat to line in the plot

ltlbl <- teste$`Trat:Ano`$Letters
ltlbl <- cbind(ltlbl, as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, str_split(names(ltlbl),":"))))
ltlbl <- ltlbl[order(ltlbl$V2, ltlbl$V1), ]


ggplot(ex,aes(x=Trat,y=cobertura,fill=Trat))+
  geom_boxplot() + scale_fill_manual(values=Paleta)+
  ylab("cobertura")+ggtitle("Melinis")+facet_wrap(~Ano,ncol=2)+
  stat_summary(geom = 'text', label = ltlbl$ltlbl, fun.y = max, aes(y = 1450))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to plot the compact letter display these is to get everything in a dataset that contains the facet and axis variables as well as the labels for plotting.

I have used the **emmeans** package for this sort of thing, partially because the package makes it very easy to get the compact letter display results into a data.frame for plotting.

Here's an example of that using your model.  I use `cld()` after `emmeans()`, which does a Tukey adjustment for the ten groups by default.

```
library(emmeans)

( cld_dat = as.data.frame( cld(emmeans(fitMelinis1, ~ Trat*Ano),
                   Letters = letters ) ) )

   Trat  Ano        emmean       SE df   lower.CL  upper.CL .group
6     C 2015 -2.224887e-13 165.7846 30 -338.57726  338.5773    a  
3     N 2009  4.507505e-14 165.7846 30 -338.57726  338.5773    a  
8     N 2015  7.860379e-14 165.7846 30 -338.57726  338.5773    a  
1     C 2009  1.750000e+00 165.7846 30 -336.82726  340.3273    a  
2    Ca 2009  8.325000e+01 165.7846 30 -255.32726  421.8273    ab 
9    NP 2015  4.137500e+02 165.7846 30   75.17274  752.3273    abc
7    Ca 2015  5.810000e+02 165.7846 30  242.42274  919.5773    abc
10    P 2015  8.095000e+02 165.7846 30  470.92274 1148.0773     bc
5     P 2009  8.992500e+02 165.7846 30  560.67274 1237.8273      c
4    NP 2009  9.902500e+02 165.7846 30  651.67274 1328.8273      c
```

I can now use this dataset in a `geom_text()` layer to add the labels.  I'll still set `y` to a constant like you did.

```
ggplot(ex, aes(x=Trat, y=cobertura, fill=Trat)) +
  geom_boxplot() + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=Paleta) +
  ylab("cobertura") +
  ggtitle("Melinis") +
  facet_wrap(~Ano,ncol=2) +
  geom_text(data = cld_dat, aes(y = 1500, label = .group))
```

[image]

You can see that each letter is in the same position over each boxplot (so some aren't centered).  If you wanted them all centered you can use `trimws()` to remove the spaces.  The `geom_text()` line would look like:

```
geom_text(data = cld_dat, aes(y = 1500, label = trimws(.group) ) )
```